# SuperKeys in Relational Database

Tags: database, relational-database

Let We have a key A for a particular relation.How many SuperKeys are possible for the relation if we have attributes as (A,B,C,D)?If we include A as a superKey it would be 8 ,If not it would be 7.So which is correct 7 or 8?

Comment: Isn't it a question for [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: If A is the *only* key then the answer is 8. A key is a minimal superkey. If there were other keys as well then there would be more superkeys.